# I would like to CRAWL ONLY SPECIFIC ITEM/DOCUMENT to FAST Search Server 2010? Programatically?

Tags: search, crawling, fast-search, crawl-rules

I would like to Crawl particular Item. To the FAST Search Server. I don't wanted to do Incremental/Full Crawl.

I can write event Handler when new Item and Check for Specific condition. If the Condition is Satisfied, I give that Item to FAST Search Server and Tell them to crawl and Create Index for It.

Is there any way to Programatically INJECT, Selected Item to FAST Search Server.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it, but you should be able to push a document to index via PowerShell

```
Docpush -c sp <filename>
```

[Check this page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff381272.aspx) for more details.

Comment: I dont wanted to PASS the document to INDEX.. I need to sent LISTITEM...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Content API for Microsoft FAST Search Server 2010 for SharePoint](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5210) but, depending on how complex the content type is, that may require a significant amount of effort to implement as you'd have to populate all of the necessary crawled properties manually.

Comment: I did tried the ContentAPI but I think the Content API is only used for Process and Index the Documents only. Not for the Content or List Ite,